# HTML form validation in conjunction with XMLRequest, validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

So I have a HTML form with some validation in place on the tags. It was working all okay until I put in place some JS to send form data, now the validation doesn't function.

```
<form>
  <input id = "username" oninput = "inputFunction(this.id)" class = "inputField" type = "text" placeholder = "Username:" name = "username" minlength = "8" required><p id = "usernameAlreadyTaken"></p>
  <input id = "psw" oninput = "inputFirstPassword(this.id)" type  = "password" class = "inputField" placeholder = "Password:" name = "psw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
  <input id = "psw2" oninput = "inputSecondPassword(this.id)" type  = "password" class = "inputField" placeholder = "Retype Password:" name = "psw"><p id = "check"></p>
  <input id = "fullname" oninput = "inputFunction(this.id)" type class = "inputField" = "text" placeholder = "Full Name:" name = "fullname" required>
  <input id = "email" oninput = "inputFunction(this.id)" type class = "inputField" = "email" placeholder = "Email Address:" name = "email" required>
  <input onclick = "registrationSendFunction()" id = "formRegisterSubmit" type = "button" value = "Create Account"  class = "registerSendButton">
</form>
```

So, this was all working as planned, *ie* with required fields and password being of the correct format etc. Then when I added the following, it stopped functioning correctly.

```
function registrationSendFunction() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = "/register";
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  let regVariable1 = document.getElementById("username").value;
  let regVariable2 = document.getElementById("psw2").value;
  let regVariable3 = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
  let regVariable4 = document.getElementById("email").value;
  let regVariable5 = document.getElementById("nationality").value;    
  let regVariable6 = document.getElementById("favourite").value;
  let registrationDetails = {
    "username" : regVariable1,
    "secret" : regVariable2,
    "fullname" : regVariable3,
    "emailAddress" : regVariable4,
    "nationality" : regVariable5,
    "favourite" : regVariable6
  }
  let dataToSend = JSON.stringify(registrationDetails)
  xhr.send(dataToSend);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        regModal.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
}
```

Any help is great, thanks.

Comment: Where do you call `registrationSendFunction()`? Or when is the form submit event attached?

Comment: apologies, its in there - formatting issue I missed

Comment: If I am not wrong, Input type button doesn't force form validation. Use type submit

Comment: perfect, thanks! I new it would be something like that, just needed another paid of eyes